# Error while trying to convert react-admin ImageInput file to Base64

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Following the official react-admin [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#handling-file-uploads) on how to implement file/image upload. I stumbled upon this error in Chrome console log:

[image]

It shows every time I call the update API method from the Edit page
the code structure is as follows:

```
export const PlayerEdit = () => (
  <Edit>
    <SimpleForm>
      <TextInput source="id" />
      <NumberInput source="active" />
      <TextInput source="name" />
      <TextInput source="email" />
      <ImageInput source="profileImgShow" multiple={true} accept="image/png">
        <ImageField source="src" title="title" />
      </ImageInput>

      <TextInput source="new_password" />
      <TextInput source="repeat_password" />

      <DateInput source="register_date" />
      <DateInput source="createdAt" />
      <DateInput source="updatedAt" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

and I wrapped the update API call with this helper function to add the upload functionality and facilitate the base64 convertion.

```
export const convertFileToBase64 = (file) => {
  console.log("rawFile", file.rawFile);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file.rawFile);
  });
};

/**
 * For posts update only, convert uploaded image in base 64 and attach it to
 * the `picture` sent property, with `src` and `title` attributes.
 */
const addUploadFeature = (requestHandler) => (resource, params) => {
  //console.log(resource, params);
  if (resource === "players") {
    // notice that following condition can be true only when `<ImageInput source="pictures" />` component has parameter `multiple={true}`
    // if parameter `multiple` is false, then data.pictures is not an array, but single object
    if (params.data.profileImgShow && params.data.profileImgShow.length) {
      // only freshly dropped pictures are instance of File

      const formerPictures = params.data.profileImgShow.filter(
        (p) => !(p.rawFile instanceof File)
      );

      const newPictures = params.data.profileImgShow.filter(
        (p) => p.rawFile instanceof File
      );

      return Promise.all(formerPictures.map(convertFileToBase64))
        .then((base64Pictures) =>
          base64Pictures.map((picture64) => ({
            src: picture64,
            title: `${newPictures.title}`,
          }))
        )
        .then((transformedNewPictures) =>
          requestHandler(resource, {
            ...params,
            data: {
              ...params.data,
              profileImgShow: [...transformedNewPictures, ...formerPictures],
            },
          })
        );
    }
  }
  // for other request types and resources, fall back to the default request handler
  //return requestHandler(type, resource, params);
};

export default addUploadFeature;
```

like this:

```
 update: addUploadFeature((resource, params) => {
    //console.log(params);
    return httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
    }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json }));
  }),
```

but for some reason the convetFileToBase64 never get called, and my guess that's because
the array of images/files supplied by ImageInput component have the type [Object] instead of [File]
or [Blob] so the filtration by type process always fails:

```
  const newPictures = params.data.profileImgShow.filter(
    (p) => p.rawFile instanceof File
  );
```

Am I doing something wrong or it's the react-admin  component supplying the wrong type of file?
The attached image shows the result of formerPictures array being passed instead of newPictures
because the filtration line return always empty array for newPictures and only formerPictures contian the file received from ImageInput.

the file I'm reciveing:

```
{
    "path": "logo192.png",
    "name": "logo192.png",
    "lastModified": 1635067661651,
    "lastModifiedDate": "2021-10-24T09:27:41.651Z",
    "webkitRelativePath": "",
    "size": 12630,
    "type": "image/png"
}
```

UPDATE:

I edited the tutorial sample on codesandbox.io to reproduce this issue, and oddly enough ImageInput returned an object of type [File] instead of [Object], however both react and react-dom versions were ^17.0.0 in sandbox and 18.0.0 on my machine, I downgraded to the older version (17.0.0) but still no luck rawFile still has the type of [Object] instead of [File] .

Update 2:
I finally noticed that in react-admin official documentation they use yarn instead of npm, so I switched to yarn and voalla everything is working as expected.

That's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "admin-panel",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "ra-data-json-server": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-admin": "^4.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be super strange, can you create github repository and send me link to reproduce? I need mainly package.json package-lock.json and yarn.lock but if you have other files, they can be also useful.

Comment: Unfortunately this was a very old project and I don't have the source code anymore, however today I just remembered this question and that I finally managed to solve the issue, I thought it could help someone out there,

Comment: I don't know if the problem is still reproducible with the current version
 of react-admin since it's development cycle seems quite fast, also I'm moving to refinejs react-admin seems too expensive to me

Comment: @Daniel check the package.json

Comment: https://codeshare.io/zyjdkE yarn.lock